# UIScrollView Cutting Off Bottom Content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm having an extremely sad time trying to get my scrollView to display content correctly.

For one page it seems to show a heap of blank content at the bottom and for another it cuts off before reaching the bottom... extremely sad. I've set the constraints of the scrollView to 0 for each side.

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQra6.png)

[Screenshot of all the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsmQ6.jpg)

I've been playing around with trying to set the contentSize but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false



    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)

    print("Width: \(self.view.bounds.size.width) Height: \(self.view.bounds.size.height) scrollView: \(self.scrollView.contentSize)")

    // prints -> Width: 375.0 Height: 667.0 scrollView: (375.0, 667.0)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what it may be with only the screenshot, but I have some suggestions. Select the ScrollView, then the ruler and:

- Check if the indicator insets are all zeros.
- In arrange select fill container horizontally and fill container vertically.
- Try to change the height value of the height to check if it is set bigger than it needs to be.

Below a screenshot of what you should see

[image: ScrollView ruler section]